# "Errors exist in the active configuration, proceed with Launch?" Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, C++, GDB, Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt

Good afternoon,

There is an error that has been occasionally occurring right after my project successfully builds. This error states "Errors exist int he active configuration, proceed with Launch?" This error usually occurs after I get some errors in the build previously, fix/clean them, and rebuild again. It occurs between the build and launching the debugger, because if I am disconnected from the remote system, it pops up before it attempts connecting to GDB.

The project builds without issues, and if I restart eclipse, I am able to build and debug without a problem. The issue is that I end up losing all of my undo states and the general discomfort of having to restart eclipse all the time.

This seems like strictly an eclipse issue,

Things I've tried that have made no difference: Cleaning the project, deleting files, etc. This seems to be a bug in eclispe,

If anyone has any knowledge on how to get rid of this prompts, please advise,

Thank you,

Comment: It seems like a bug in Eclipse/CDT. Update to 4.4.2 and see if it's fixed. Report a bug to developers otherwise (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/). IIRC there is also a "don't show this warning" again check-box, which is not a solution, but might come handy.